# How to increase limit from 20000 variables in REST API in flowable?

Tags: activiti, bpmn, flowable

When making a REST API call to query historic tasks using the parameter "includeProcessVariables": "true" , a maximum of 20,000 variables are returned. The results of the REST API when using "includeProcessVariables": "true" are cut off as soon as the 20,000th variable is in the REST API response.

A customer have around 500 process variable in on process and for that he is only able to get the first 40 process Data with includeProcessVariables=true.

In docs , they have mentioned that the limit of 20000 is for performance reason.
Can this limit be changed in flowable.

I am thinking to increase the limit to 100000.

Same issue here https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/issues/1348 , https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ACTIVITI-1065, https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/commit/fcf56439fb227093fcc1708642b893c0e28212f4

Comment: In my humble opinion you are doing something wrong if you have 500 and more variables per process instance. You either have monolithic process definition or you store way to much business data in your BPM.

Comment: Please look for ways to reduce the number of variables. The current limit is imposed "for performance reasons" isn't something you want to casually ignore :)